# how do I use tar -C on Snow Leopard when creating an archive?

Tags: macos, command-line, archiving, tar, syntax

The man page states

```
-C directory
      In c and r mode, this changes the directory before adding the following files.
```

However, tar does not change to the directory I specify, but instead reports

```
tar: <folder name>: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
```

for every folder in the directory I run the tar command in.

Do I really have to do something like

```
cd <folder> && tar ... && cd -
```

or is there a way to get this work ?

Comment: The command line you're running is...?

Comment: yes, provide the commandline you are trying to get to work, not only the error messages.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to this. The command line is not very spectacular:

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot use the `-C` option like you presume in this question.

Section [`6.10.1 Changing the Working Directory`](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_chapter/Choosing.html#SEC116) in the GNU manual for `tar` describes the `-C` option like this,

> To change the working directory in the middle of a list of file names, either on the command line or in a file specified using ‘--files-from’ (‘-T’), use ‘--directory’ (‘-C’). This will change the working directory to the specified directory after that point in the list.
>
> `‘--directory=directory’`
>   `‘-C directory’`
>
> Changes the working directory in the middle of a command line.
>
> For example,
>
> `$ tar -c -f jams.tar grape prune -C food cherry`
>
> will place the files ‘grape’ and ‘prune’ from the current directory into the archive ‘jams.tar’, followed by the file ‘cherry’ from the directory ‘food’. This option is especially useful when you have several widely separated files that you want to store in the same archive.
>
> Note that the file ‘cherry’ is recorded in the archive under the precise name ‘cherry’, not ‘food/cherry’. Thus, the archive will contain three files that all appear to have come from the same directory; if the archive is extracted with plain ‘tar --extract’, all three files will be written in the current directory.

There are a few more examples at the manual page...

---

Update:
I usually do not mix up files from different paths into a single tar-ball.
However, if that is what you desire, there are two things that can be done,

1. Use the `-T` option with a list of directories/files you want to pack together.
   That will collect all things together with extra path-prefixes.
2. Use the `-h` option on a 'link image' directory
   (you make one of those with a script to create links to files and directories of interest under a new and empty directory)
   The `-h` option used on such a directory will create a single tar-ball that represents the file layout under that directory.

Comment: i'm not sure OS X uses GNU tar (unless the OP has installed it specifically).  i'd expect it provides a BSD tar by default.  (tho the example syntax given is a good one to test with.)

Comment: I did read that. Tried out the example and it works.
Seems like I can not use wildcards with -C to add all the files in the directory I jumped to, i.e. -C food *

Comment: No, indeed, the * will be expanded by the shell based on your current directory, before it's handed to tar

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer using subshells to get *tar* into "position".  I've never learned the `-C` option, so I'm not sure how it works.

Assume my CWD is */path/a*, and I want to create a tarball of */path/b/foo* without the leading */path/b*:

```
user@host:/path/a$ ( cd /path/b && tar czf ~/tarball.tgz foo )
user@host:/path/a$
```

The resulting tarball contains the directory *foo/* and all its contents, but not the leading */path/b*.  The subshell executes the *cd*, then the *tar* if the *cd* succeeds, then exits back to my original shell in the same CWD.

Comment: I might have to resort to that solution, but there's reasons why I would love to get the -C option going.

Answer (score 1):

tar -C doesn't work with wildcards because as Henno stated in one of the comments:

> * will be expanded by the shell based on your current directory, before it's handed to tar

So if you are trying to do something like:

```
tar -cvzf myfile.tgz -C somepath *
```

It won't work. As far as I can tell you will have to change directory first like quack quixote suggests.